# CRM Email not formatting HTML via c#

Tags: email, crm

I am trying to send n email through crm but with HTML in the Body.  I am sending the email correctly through CRM, but when I open it up (Contact > History) I open the email and see that the body does not have the XML encoded as HTML. Here is what I have so far. My Body of the email is below this code. I've accomplished this using MailMessage() but that will not send it through CRM, only via SMTP. ANy ideas?

```
var emailTemplateBody = GetEmailTemplateBody();
        var _getEmailVariables = getEmailVariables(emailTemplateBody);

        // Create a FROM activity party for the email.
        activityparty fromParty = new activityparty();
        fromParty.partyid = new Lookup();
        fromParty.partyid.type = EntityName.systemuser.ToString();
        fromParty.partyid.Value = new Guid("C82755FB-6369-DB11-98AE-00145E7F535F");

        //Create a TO activity party for email
        activityparty toParty = new activityparty();
        toParty.partyid = new Lookup();
        toParty.partyid.type = EntityName.contact.ToString();
        toParty.partyid.Value = new Guid("74CD3907-5BC9-E311-9C41-005056850017");

        //Create a new email
        email emailInstance = new email();

        //set email parameters
        emailInstance.from = new activityparty[] { fromParty };
        emailInstance.to = new activityparty[] { toParty };
        emailInstance.subject = "Who Cares";
        emailInstance.description = _getEmailVariables;
        emailInstance.mimetype = ""

        //Create a GUId for the email
        Guid emailId = _crmServiceInstance.Create(emailInstance);

        //Create a SendEmailRequest
        SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest();
        request.EmailId = emailId;
        request.IssueSend = true;
        request.TrackingToken = "";


        //Execute request
        _crmServiceInstance.Execute(request);
```

XML code that needs to be in HTML:

```
"<template><text><![CDATA[<p><font size=2 face=\"Tahoma, Verdana, Arial\">Hi: |contact.FullName|</font></p>\r\n<p><font size=2 face=\"Tahoma, Verdana, Arial\"></font> </p><font size=2 face=\"Tahoma, Verdana, Arial\">\r\n<ul style=\"list-style-type:disc;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px;text-transform:none;color:rgb(0,0,0);padding-bottom:0px;text-align:left;padding-top:0px;font:14px/19px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica;padding-left:20px;margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;letter-spacing:normal;padding-right:0px;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);text-indent:0px\">\r\n<li style=\"list-style-position:outside;padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:0px;margin:5px 0px;padding-right:0px\">Content Line 2 = |New_manheimsubscription.new_externalbillingsubscriptionid| \r\n<li style=\"list-style-position:outside;padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-left:0px;margin:5px 0px;padding-right:0px\">DogButter is gross</li></ul></font>]]></text></template>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put everything in HTML format as below and add that to the description of email. That way we should be able to get the body in HTML format as expected.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This approach worked for me when i had to create the description of the email with some of the HTML objects.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Can you please check the tags inside the CDATA part. I believe that is not formed properly. One of the <li> is missing closing tag. May be that is the problem why its not coming as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have used sucessfully HTML code inside the body of the email.
I'am using Dynamics 365 v9.0.

> 

This is a paragraph 1.

This is a paragraph 2.

This is a paragraph 3.